# Wi-Fi Adapter problem

Tags: usb, wifi, connection, wireless-adapter

Past few days ago I bought a Wi-Fi adapter for the Raspberry Pi, it just came today. When I tested it the Raspberry Pi wasn't recognizing the adapter, yet when I put it to my PC its perfectly fine. The adapter is a Realtek RTL8188EU. I'm presuming that I bought the wrong adapter.

Comment: What dongle usb id and vendor is reported by the dmesg or lsusb commands?

Comment: When I used sudo lsusb it didn't really detect the adapter. I used sudo lsusb two times, with the adapter and without, there was really no difference.

Comment: If you take the dongle out, wait a couple of seconds, and then reinsert the dongle the last few lines of dmesg should identify the dongle.

Comment: I did, it didn't really detect anything. Perhaps I'll test it out again when I come back home. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Realtek Wi-Fi dongles do work on the pi, i had the same problem with a different Realtek dongle when i first tried to use it. You should start by getting an internet connection with a network cable and making sure it is up to date by using the commands :

> sudo apt-get update

Once that has run you run:

> sudo apt-get upgrade

After a reboot then you can check if the Realtek firmware is installed and if not it will install, by running the command:

> sudo apt-get install firmware-realtek

One more reboot and hopefully your Wi-Fi will work.

Comment: I'll test it when I come back home, thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't have to pay shipping to resend the adapter. Thank you!